# Web API ModelBinding From URI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

So I have a custom Model Binder implemented for `DateTime` type and I register it like below:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.BindParameter(typeof(DateTime), new CurrentCultureDateTimeAPI());
}
```

and then I have setup 2 sample actions to see if my custom model binding takes place:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public void BindDateTime([FromUri]DateTime datetime)
    {
        //http://localhost:26171/web/api/BindDateTime?datetime=09/12/2014
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public void BindModel([FromUri]User user)
    {
        //http://localhost:26171/web/api/BindModel?Name=ibrahim&JoinDate=09/12/2014
    }
```

When I run and invoke both actions from mentioned URLs, `user`'s `JoinDate` property successfully gets bound using the custom binder I configured but `BindDateTime`'s `datetime` parameter does not get bound using the custom binder.

I have already specified in config that all `DateTime` should use my custom binder then why the indifference? Suggestions are highly appreciated.

CurrentCultureDateTimeAPI.cs:

```
public class CurrentCultureDateTimeAPI: IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var date = value.ConvertTo(typeof(DateTime), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        bindingContext.Model = date;
        return true;
    }
}
```

NOTE: If I use `[FromUri(Binder=typeof(CurrentCultureDateTimeAPI))]DateTime datetime` then it works as expected but then again why?

Comment: Possibly that's because you're setting a [FromUri] attribute - web API uses formatters instead of model binding, so your custom model binder is not used. Try removing [FromUri] attribute in BindDateTime method.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin No. It does not work.

Comment: You're right, [FromUri] has nothing to do with this. I've tried to reproduce your scenario - everything works fine, my custom model binder is called in both methods. Could you provide the CurrentCultureDateTimeAPI code?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin Sure. It's in the post now. Also I would appreciate if you could provide your reproduced code of my implementation for reference.

Comment: @Md.lbrahim: I just tested the above code by creating a `web-api 2` solution and it works just fine. The code above is perfectly alright. Could you check if your `route` or if there is any other problem ? Put a breakpoint and check if the method is hit.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. the actions are getting hit right. But my custom model binder is not getting hit like I mentioned above. Everything else seems to work just fine. [Here](https://app.box.com/s/te13tnh3ezbs8za8lk1y) is the solution.

Comment: Well, I've found the line code, that is responsible for such weird behavior - it's the attribute routing configuration: config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); Once you'll comment this line, everything works as it should. Somehow it get's in the way of your model binding.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin: I doubt if it is. That line `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes` just enables the `attributes routing`. Not sure if this gets in the way of model binding

Comment: Well, I was surprised either, try it yourself :) I've tried to find the cause in web api 2 sources (https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/HttpConfigurationExtensions.cs and https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Routing/AttributeRoutingMapper.cs), but with no luck.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. IlyaLuzyanin is correct. If I remove that line. Model binding takes place as expected. But do not know why?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin Luzyanin: Yes, I am surprised too :) Check out my answer below

Comment: I found that if I was specifying the type in the routing attribute, model binding no longer took place. e.g. [Route("action/{fromDate}")] works, whereas [Route("action/{fromDate:DateTime?}")] does not bind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty surprising too :)

My initial doubt was this line:

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.BindParameter(typeof(DateTime), new CurrentCultureDateTimeAPI());
```

**MSDN** says `GlobalConfiguration` => `GlobalConfiguration provides a global System.Web.HTTP.HttpConfiguration for ASP.NET application`.

But for weird reasons this does not seem to work with this particular scenario.

So,

Just add this line inside the static class `WebApiConfig`

```
 config.BindParameter(typeof(DateTime), new CurrentCultureDateTimeAPI());
```

so that your `WebAPIConfig` file looks like:

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "web/{controller}/{action}/{datetime}",
                defaults: new { controller = "API", datetime = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.BindParameter(typeof(DateTime), new CurrentCultureDateTimeAPI());
        }
```

And everything works fine because this method is directly invoked by `WebAPI framework` so for sure your `CurrentCultureDateTimeAPI` gets registered.

Checked this with your solution and works great.

Note: *(From the comments)* You can still support `Attribute Routing` and you need not comment out this line `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()`.

*But still, It would be great if somebody can tell why `GlobalConfiguration` does not work out*

Answer (score -6):

It looks like you want to post some data to the server.  Try to use FromData and post JSON.  FromUri is typically used to fetch some data.  Use WebAPI's conventions and allow it to work for you.